# SSRS Change textbox color depending on the time

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, textbox

I am trying to change the color of a textbox depending on the time in the box. so if the time is over `5minutes` then the box is to turn`red`, if it is less then 5 then it is to be transparent.

the problem i am getting is that it does not like using time but I have tried a number of different ways and none seem to work. below is to show the idea of what i would like it to do!

Thanks!
Thomas

```
  =IIF(Fields!SegmentTime.Value < 00:05:00, "Red","Transparent")
```

Comment: Problem with SSRS is that is creates a report and just shows it to the client, in no way it is possible to do timebased events on the page because it is all rather static at the moment after the report is generated. it is possible to refresh the page after x-amount of minutes/seconds etc...

Comment: I have never work with time but it's perhaps a problem with your condition. As i understand you have a time specified in that column and when the value is under 5 minutes you want it red? It should work, it's static. You could try to do a iif specifying a value for example : if < 5 min display hello, else display Bye. If it works... then go to the background field and specify a conditional color with that condition using color. (sorry i don't have ssrs at work, i'll give an example when coming back at home)

Comment: What is the datatype of your Fields!SegmentTime.Value? Could you give me some exemplary values being returned by SegmentTime field?